# How to politely decline to take someone's help?

Tags: politeness, email, professions

So I was looking to take someone's professional service and he offered me a quote. It was too high. So I declined it. Then he **offered** to give me some unofficial service as a courtesy.

All of this happened via email.

Now I don't want to take his courtesy service even for free for various reasons.

What's a polite way of saying so (via email)?

Comment: ... ask abby ...

Comment: @BlessedGeek, I'm sorry?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dear_Abby

Comment: http://news.yahoo.com/dear-abby/

Comment: @BlessedGeek, ok, so what about it? Is she on here?

Comment: Abby would say, "Tell him you already have a boyfriend".

Comment: Quoth Nancy Sinatra Reagan: *Just say no*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell him that you're grateful for his kind offer but that won't be necessary.

If pressed for a reason then say thanks again but you've already found an alternative solution to your problem, or you're now committed to an alternative supplier.